# AWS Athena found no records on csv file

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I got 2Gb csv file (pipe separated) in s3,

Run a glue crawler on it, created new table.

When run a query from aws-athena it found zero record (even though it return the columns correctly)
didn't applied any partition, just run the crawler as default as possible.
any suggestion?

*note  - used aws consol for all actions*

Comment: What's the S3 path you provided in the crawler?

Comment: s3://my-bucket-test/short_inputs/   while the files in subfolder: 2019/2/1/file.txt

Comment: It's an old question, anyway maybe this note will be helpful. We had problems with particular csv datasources and the default serialization lib which the default crawler put into Glue table properties (`org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe`). In our case, the recordset queried by Athena reported empty contents (not zero num of records, but empty records in fact) for some datasources using this serialization lib. What helped is to change (in table properties) the serialization lib to `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde`.

Answer (score 0):

The possibility that the query is not returning the data is

If you have specified the file name in the bucket name while Adding
    the crawler.

```
Let's say your bucket name is testbucket and the csv file is test.csv, 
so while adding the crawler you need to specify your bucket name as s3://testbucket/ 
and not s3://testbucket/test.csv
```

Also, if the fields are separated by pipe, then they will be displayed under single column only as the file extension is .csv (comma separated). So ideally the fields should be comma separated in order to fetch the proper output.

Hence, try specifying the bucket name as mentioned above. Hope this will return the data.

If the data is still not returned, try creating a new crawler and while creating the new crawler do not use the existing IAM role. Create a new role. Sometimes, IAM policies make a glitch while fetching the data.

Comment: 10x, tried to put the folder, not the file, didn't help. File is pipe separated, my suspect is that some issue with the file parsing, even though the crawler claimed to succeed, and recognized the all columns names and num of lines. Only Athen doesn't found the records..